# Android Search Activity Query

Tags: android, search

Is it possible to create a suggestion list (a drop down list) *in the same activity* as the user types ?
ListView contains simple text and I want the user to select the text from the suggested list only but I want to sort it with user input.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AutoCompleteTextView or TextWatcher

Comment: Thanks. I tried TextWatcher ShowSuggestionss.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
& it worked. :)